# What was on the piece of paper?

Tags: lateral-thinking

A man walks into a restaurant and finds a piece of paper on the floor, he picks it up and gives it to the waiter who then gives it to his manager. The manager calls the police and the man gets arrested. Taken to court the judge asks to see the piece of paper, then decides for man to be executed. The executioner asks him what he did wrong? The man shows him the piece of paper. The executioner then decides to help him escape!

The question: What was on the piece of paper?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could it be...

> A counterfeit dollar bill? (Or more likely a 20, 50, or 100)

Explanation:

> He gets arrested for trying to pay with a counterfeit bill. The executioner let him escape because he thought he was being bribed.

Comment: What a reason to be executed!

Comment: @kedarguru Lets just say the judge woke up on the wrong side of the bed that morning :)

Comment: I think the judge is having an off day. Rather than submit it to evidence, he just gives the paper back to the man after the sentencing!

Comment: Great answer! Got it spot on. Under strange circumstances :)

Comment: @CherryPlaysRoblox Yes, but unfortunately the judge didn't buy that story.

Comment: Just going to leave this link here : [Penalties by country for creating counterfeit money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterfeit_money#Penalties_by_country_for_creating_counterfeit_money)

Comment: @CherryPlaysRoblox Answerers putting their solutions in spoiler tags is of little benefit if people then give the answer away in the comments.  Try being more indirect in alluding to the answer instead of saying or referencing it directly, or using [ROT-13](http://www.rot13.com/) encoding or similar if you must, to preserve the mystery for future would-be solvers. :)